# Chart title to change to the text of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I haven't been able to find if this is possible but does anyone know if it is possible to make the chart title change to say whatever is in a cell? For example: the Chart title says "Last Month Returns: Costco" but "Costco" comes from Cell A2 because it could change to Wal-Mart and the title would then be "Last Month Returns: Wal-Mart"

I think it could be done via macro but if I can avoid macros that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chart title can be linked to a cell, but not to a combination of text and a cell. So if cell A2 contains "Costco" say, then you should enter a formula in cell B2 (or some other cell) with a formula like

```
="Last Month Returns: " & A2
```

Then select the chart title, and while it is selected type into the formula bar:

```
=B2
```

That should do it.

Comment: This is the best method. By doing this, you can have your "A2" be things like drop-downs or other filtered datasets (like pivot tables).

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.